# Under what smoothness conditions can we approximate a function by tensor products

Tags: real-analysis

I am aware that if $\phi$ is a smooth, compactly supported function on $\mathbf{R}^d$, then there exists a series of functions $\phi_n$, with $\phi_n(x) = \alpha_{n1}(x_1) \dots \alpha_{nd}(x_d)$ for some compactly supported, smooth functions $\alpha_{ni}$, such that $D_\alpha \phi_n$ converges to $D_\alpha \phi$ uniformly for each multi-index $\alpha$.

My question is what conditions are necessary on three parameters $d$, $n$, and $m$, so that, given an $n$ times continuously differentiable, compactly supported function $\phi$ on $\mathbf{R}^d$,  we can approximate it by $\phi_n(x) = \alpha_{n1}(x_1)\alpha_{nd}(x_d)$ for compactly supported, $n$ times continously differentiable functions $\alpha_{ni}$, such that $D_\alpha \phi_n$ converges to $D_\alpha \phi$ uniformly for each multi-index $\alpha$ of order less than $m$.

The standard Fourier sum argument showing the density of tensor products of functions shows the result holds true if $m + d \leq n$. Can one do better?